# Cannot update entity with JPA because the @onetoone dependent property is immutable but there is no @immutable annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to update rows:

```
 @PutMapping(value = "/updateEdits")
    @Transactional
    public void updateGeometry(@RequestBody List<Geometry> values){

        geometryRepository.saveAll(values);
    }
```

But it does not work.

> WARN 12400 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister     : HHH000502: The [feature] property of the [com.samm.fiberplanner.entity.Geometry] entity was modified, but it won't be updated because the property is immutable.

Releated entities:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Geometry {
    @Id
    private Long gId;

    private String type;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String coordinates;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private Feature feature;

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Feature {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long fId;
    private String type;
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "feature",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Properties properties;
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "feature",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Geometry geometry;
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "geo_json_id")
    private GeoJson geoJson;
}
```

Why is [feature] property is immutable? How can i update the table?

Comment: try adding `@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})` or `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` above `private Feature feature;`

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos tried but nothing changed. It still gives same warning.

Answer (score 1):

Add `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` to your Entity relationShip in this relationShip

```
@OneToOne
@MapsId
private Feature feature;
```

, it will make the entity mutable

Comment: it will make the entity mutable

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works

```
@Entity(mutable = "true")
```

Comment: There is property called as mutable in @Entity annotation